# How do I instantiate policies in Chrome on mac?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, python, group-policy

This is the set of policies that I want for my installation of Chrome (converted to json):

```
{
   "chromePolicies": {
      "BrowserAddPersonEnabled": {
         "level": "recommended",
         "scope": "machine",
         "source": "platform",
         "value": false
      },
      "BrowserGuestModeEnabled": {
         "level": "recommended",
         "scope": "machine",
         "source": "platform",
         "value": false
      },
      "ExtensionInstallForcelist": {
         "level": "mandatory",
         "scope": "machine",
         "source": "platform",
         "value": [ "pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe", "mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa", "cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm" ]
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried to instantiate these policies in a number of ways, including:

1. Edited the `com.google.Chrome.plist` in `/Library/Managed Preferences/Preferences`
2. Edited the `com.google.Chrome.plist` in `/Library/Preferences`
3. Ran these commands:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome BrowserAddPersonEnabled -bool false
defaults write com.google.Chrome BrowserGuestModeEnabled -bool false
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallForcelist -array \
  '{ pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe; }' \
  '{ mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa; }' \
  '{ cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm; }'
```

4. Installed [mcxToProfile](https://github.com/timsutton/mcxToProfile) and converted my policies file to a profile and then installed that profile on my Mac OS, according to these [instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9020077?hl=en). That was with this command: `python mcxToProfile.py --plist /Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist   --identifier com.google.Chrome`

Every time I edit the policies, they fail to stick. They might appear in Chrome for the current session but they go away after I restart my computer (specifically the extension install forcelist).

Comment: You might try instead to [Use master preferences for Chrome Browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en).

Comment: Do I need to pay Google for this or is it simply making the file and then having the admin on this computer push it to `/Library/Google/Google Chrome Master Preferences`. I'll add that the user who uses Chrome is not the admin

Comment: This is a tool for admins, so you can use it. To enforce them see in the article about Chrome policies.

Comment: Awesome, so I'll create the master preferences and then all the non-admin users will be restricted to using Chrome under those settings. Can they install a new Chrome?

Comment: It's a matter of permissions, and you're the admin.

Comment: Did you use the above method?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I'm confident that it'll work. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google article
[Use master preferences for Chrome Browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en)
discusses the question of deploying default preferences to Chrome users.
These preferences are applied when users first open the Chrome Browser.

The article says:

> To apply settings that you don’t want users to change, enforce Chrome
> policies on
> [Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7649838) or
> [Mac](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9020077) computers
> instead.
>
> If a setting is managed by a Chrome policy and also configured in the
> master_preferences file, the policy takes precedence and users can’t
> edit the setting. For details, see [View a device’s current Chrome
> policies](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9024365)

These preferences are contained in the `master_preferences` file.
An example such file can be
[downloaded](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/Y2dvgj4vUhoxiiLqzWmhjpLW3b3rBaLWuW8L)
as a starting point and then edited using a text editor to add the
required parameters. Its format is JSON.